# Why is this array value changing after I "store" it?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

```
public static Stack<int[]> myMethod(int[] state) {

    int[][] checked = new int[4][4];
    int[][] temporary = new int[4][4];
    Stack<int[]> checklol = new Stack();
    int farmer = state[0];
    int[] valid = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    int[] temp = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    // invert farmer
    farmer = 1 - farmer;

    valid[0] = farmer;
    valid[1] = state[1];
    valid[2] = state[2];
    valid[3] = state[3];

    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        valid[i] = 1 - valid[i];
        if (checkSolution(valid)) {
            checklol.push(valid);
        }
        valid[i] = 1 - valid[i];
    }

    return checklol;
}
```

So basically I start out with an array that is [1,1,1,1]
And what I do is flip the first one to a zero. Which is what i do in farmer - 1
Then in that loop, I go through the second number and flip that one. Then I call that checked method, and if it’s valid then I wanted to push it to the stack. Then I change that second number back to the original. 
Then I do the same thing with the third number. And then the fourth.

My issue is that the array pushed to the stack is changed by the iterations following them. So I had [1,0,1,1] on the stack but then it changed it to [1,1,1,1] after it had been pushed. But I don't want that to happen.

It boils down to this: **Once it's on the stack I don't want the value to be changed any longer. But yet it is changed.**

I apologize in advance if this is unclear whatsoever.

Comment: What do you know about objects and references?

Comment: @immibis Not too much

Comment: Could you show us your `checkSolution` method? What I believe the problem is, look at the last line of your `for` loop (before you close the loop) although you checked the solution, still you called `valid[i] = 1 - valid[i]` which may be the problem. You might need to put an `if` statement there to check if it's in the stack or not.

Comment: please consider accepting your own answer by clicking the check-mark

Comment: @tarik I have to wait two days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by first cloning the array and then pushing it to the stack.

Comment: You should accept your own answer to get it off the "unanswered" queue